# EF6 marking removed entities as "Added"

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Another EF6 confusion.

I have a model with `Parent -> Collection<Child>` relation. I may add and remove entities to the child collection before calling `SaveChanges`. For instance:

```
Children.Add(child);
Children.Remove(child);
Context.SaveChanges();
```

After calling `Add`, I can see the ChangeTracker goes and updates the child's parentID and Parent properties when I check the HasChanges property. Similarly, when I Remove, the ChangeTracker sets the Parent property to Null. Makes sense.

Here is where my issue is. To make sure the user can save changes without issue, I call a method on the context which tries to validate (using validation attributes) any entity marked as "Added" or "Modified". The interesting thing about this is that even after I remove the new child entity, it still comes up in the ChangeTracker as "Added", despite the fact that it has no parent, is not a member of the original collection, and does not get added to the database when I call SaveChanges();

My question is: is this correct behaviour? It seems strange that the ChangeTracker can correctly detect and flag Added entities, but can't seem to mark them as ignored or deleted when they're removed from child collections. Is there any way to get the ChangeTracker to register the entity as deleted or ignored other than manually setting the entity or removing from the main DbSet.

Btw I am adding entities to the child collection on the parent, not the Child DbSet in the DbContext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Children.Add(child);` call returns an entity entry wrapper.

(alternatively, run `context.Entry(child)` to get the entry).

You can set the state to deleted like this: `context.Entry(child).State = EntityState.Deleted`

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/entity-state

Answer (score 0):

What is likely happening is that you are actually adding and removing a different reference for the same child, It could also be a problem with your entity mapping confusing EF. I had run the following test and EF handled the scenario properly without attempting to insert an invalid child row, or producing any errors:

```
using (var context = new AppDbContext())
{
    var parent = context.Parents.Include(x => x.Children).Single(x => x.ParentId == 2);
    var child = new Child("Test", 2, parent);
    parent.Children.Add(child);
    parent.Children.Remove(child);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I had tried this with both eager loading the children (above) and without the eager load in case that made any difference to the proxy behaviour. I also tried with a required parent relationship vs. an optional one. (Null-able parent ID in child)

What will cause problems like this is if you were to do something like:

```
using var context = new SoftDeleteDbContext();
var parent = context.Parents.Include(x => x.Children).Single(x => x.ParentId == 2);
parent.Children.Add(new Child("Test", 2, parent));
// ...
parent.Children.Remove(new Child("Test", 2, parent));
context.SaveChanges();
```

As an example... If you create/retrieve a reference to add to a parent, then at a later stage want to remove that child either create or fetch a different reference to the same child, then EF would be working with two separate references and would end up ignoring the call to remove the second reference since it wouldn't recognize it as a tracked entity and that reference doesn't actually exist in the parent's Children collection. The safest way to remove child relations from a parent is to ensure the parent's children is eager loaded, then get the actual reference to remove from the parent:

```
using var context = new SoftDeleteDbContext();
var parent = context.Parents.Include(x => x.Children).Single(x => x.ParentId == 2);
var child = new Child("Test", 2, parent);
parent.Children.Add(child);
/// ... 

var childToRemove = parent.Children.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Test");
if (childToRemove != null)
    parent.Children.Remove(childToRemove);

context.SaveChanges();
```

Assuming you have a unique value available for the item you added, otherwise you need to be careful to ensure you are dealing with the exact same reference that was added to the parent.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for the answer, but this isn't the case here. I'm only passing around 1 reference to the child, not newing up a new entity. Our entities don't have a ```Required``` attribute for the relationship, but to make sure orphaned entities aren't saved we override the SaveChanges method to find any child entity that has a null parent and delete it. I believe we did this because EF6 kept trying to save orphaned children for some reason.

Comment: With the tests I've run it should be working without the seemingly disconnected instances triggering an Add after removing them. A quick way to verify for certain would be `var isSame = ReferenceEquals(child, parent.Children.Single(x => x.Id == child.Id);` Using the ID or other unique attributes of the child that should return that exact instance from within the parent. If that returns `True` then something very unique is happening. :)